# Android remove activities from back stack

Tags: android

I have 3 different views (activities). The first one is a view where you can select the mode, the second one contains a list of items available on that mode, and the third one is a player to play the content of that mode. In each of them, I have a `BroadcastReceiver`. Those are registered to receive the same event (a bluetooth disconnection event).

I want to have the following : if I am in the second or third activity, if the bluetooth goes off on the device, I go back to the first activity (destroying the 2 and the 3 ones).

How can I manage to do that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this when the event occurs:

```
Intent i = new Intent(the_current_activity.this,first_activity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly what I want to do. Doing it that way, it looks like I am destroying the first activity and recreating it. I'd like to keep it alive